# Does it matter whether you choose not to expand a node vs. not add it to the queue in A* with an explored, closed set? (Graph search)

Tags: search, graph, a-star

I'm currently taking the Berkeley AI class on EdX, and we're going over A* search. I've worked with A* graph search before, and I implemented it so that when adding successors to the fringe/queue, I won't add a successor if it's in the fringe or in the explored/closed set already. However, the professor in the class was saying that for A* graph search, we should add nodes to the fringe and then skip them if we pop them off and they're already in the explored set (i.e. refuse to expand them but still add repeated nodes to the fringe).

The pseudocode on Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star#Pseudocode, for A* seems to do it the other way, where we only add it to the fringe/queue if it is not in the explored/closed set already. However, it also has a part that seems like Dijkstra's, where it makes sure that the g-score of the successor is minimal.

This is all assuming that we are using a consistent, optimal heuristic. Could someone help me get a better understanding of the consequences of implementing it either way  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about 2 approaches for dealing with previously encountered nodes

In your first approach you pop an item from your queue to add it to your closed set. When doing so, you have to add its successors to the queue. If a successor is already on the queue, then you just update its value (so it is minimal). This will require at least n lookup operations (one for each successor of your node). Each time a node is already on your queue, you have to compare its value to the new one and possibly update the priority. In the worst case scenario, you have to perform n lookups, n comparisons and n update operations on your queue.

In your second approach (the one from your professor), all successors are put in the queue without checking if they were already there. This will require only n insertions when evaluating a node. You will however have to check, each time you pop a node of the queue, if its already in your closed set or not, before you can explore it. This will require one lookup operation (although not on your queue) per node you added to your queue. One node can be present in your queue multiple times (while in the first approach, there will be only one copy in the queue).

As you can see, the difference in both approaches will depend on the type of queue you use (e.g. fibonacci heaps, binary heaps,...) and the cost of the respective operations. If update operations are expensive, then the second approach will be faster. The second approach does require more memory for your queue (as it can contain more than one copy of the same node at the same time). The queue will be bigger and this will have an impact on the operations you do on it.

You should look at the queue you use and determine the best approach based on the required operations and your graph.